# ImageMagick version cannot be found - rmagick install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, redmine, rmagick

Super confused and a first time Ruby user... I already have rmagick installed as denoted here:

```
actionmailer (3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.5)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
coderay (1.0.7)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
mocha (0.12.3)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mongrel_service (0.3.4 i386-mswin32)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
pg (0.14.0 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
prototype-rails (3.2.1)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.6)
railties (3.2.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rmagick (2.12.0 mswin32)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
win32-service (0.5.2 mswin32)
```

But when I run **bundle install**. It gives me this output.

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.6) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.6) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.6) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.6) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.6) 
Using activeresource (3.2.6) 
Using bundler (1.1.5) 
Using coderay (1.0.7) 
Using fastercsv (1.5.5) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using metaclass (0.0.1) 
Using mocha (0.12.3) 
Using mysql (2.8.1) 
Using net-ldap (0.3.1) 
Using pg (0.14.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.6) 
Using rails (3.2.6) 
Using prototype-rails (3.2.1) 
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8) 
Using rack-openid (1.3.1) 
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/wamp/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/wamp/ruby/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Note that I'm attempting to complete a redmine installation and need rmagick to continue using rake.

My ruby version is 1.8.7 and rubygem version is 1.3.7. Thanks.

**Update:**

So after hearing that my existing rmagick was an old version I ran:

```
gem uninstall rmagick
```

and successfully uninstalled my existing gem. After which I attempted a bundle install again which failed exactly the same as before.

This time however I went to my folder (C:\wamp\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rmagick-2.13.1) where it said the files would still be stored. There I ran a new build via

```
gem build rmagick.gemspec
```

The build succeeded so I think we're getting somewhere. I ran:

```
gem install rmagick-2.13.1.gem --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:\ImageMagick\6.3.5-Q8\lib --with-opt-include=c:\ImageMagick\6.3.5-Q8\include
```

and got this output (*note that I'm no longer getting Invalid Drive but this is otherwise identical to before*):

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/wamp/ruby/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

So now I'm just working on why it can't determine the ImageMagick version...

Comment: per my comment below my mkmf.log only has this: checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes --------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not exactly answer the question... it's likely that as a novice user I borked my installation at some point.

Back-tracking and uninstalling everything that I had previously installed and then following the [installation instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache#Install-Redmine) again resolved the issue.

Note that this time around even in parts where it said, "although future versions should also work" I instead specified the exact versions that were mentioned in the article at the time of writing.

Comment: if you face some problems with rmagic/ImageMagick source, reinstall ImageMagick to older version - I have successfull bundle only ofter reinstalling ImageMagick from 6.8.8 to 6.6.7

Answer (score 0):

There is an old version of rmagick, though bundler try to install a newer version. The build of the new version went something wrong. You should check the log file to find why.

Comment: The extent of my mkmf.log is checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

Comment: Only one line? I guess the error info "Invalid drive specification. Unable to get ImageMagick version" is important to solve this. I'm not sure what it means. I have no ruby on a windows.  On my OS X, after checking ruby version, the next step is to detect gcc.

Comment: Please see my update if you have the time. I've now gotten past the invalid drive specification miraculously. :)

Comment: Sorry I still cannot be sure the problem. Here is my guess: After check the info on rubyforge about rmagick installing on windows, both rmagick and ImageMagick are recommended to install by a special gem only on windows(including some exe file). But this special gem only has version 2.12. Maybe you need a cygwin environment to compile the 2.13 gem.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is a native library, used by RMagick to manipulate images. It seems something might be wrong with your ImageMagick installation, and RMagick is unable to detect the ImageMagick version installed on your environment.

On the console, when you type 'identify', do you have the output of an application or just an file not found error?

Comment: My output for typing 'identify' into my command prompt was:
Version: ImageMagick 6.3.5 08/10/07 QA http://www.imagemagick.org
... and some misc help info.

Comment: Do you have a gist of the mkmf.log? Thanks.